# Send data from view to viewmodel using command (mvvm)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

How can I send data from view to view model? So that when I click a button, it sends the data (startDate, endDate, product and category) to view model. In the view model, I will use the 4 values as parameters of method call.

Here is code from View:

```
    <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding startDate}"
        ......>

    <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding endDate}"
        ......>

    <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding productName}"
        ......>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="X"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Y"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Z"/>
    </ComboBox>

    <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding category}"
        ......>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="CD/Web"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Operating System"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="OSConfiguration"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="..."/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="..."/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="..."/>
    </ComboBox>

    <Button Command="{Binding AddMatricCommand}" Content="Query" 
    ....../>
```

Here is the code in View Model, and I need startDate, endDate, product and category as parameters to call the methods in View Model.

```
{
    [Export(typeof(IShell))]
    public class ShellViewModel : Screen
    {
        #region Members
    private AnalyticsManager _manager;
    private DataTable _table;

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Public property that is bound to the DataGrid in the view
    /// </summary>
    public DataTable Table
    {
        get
        {
            return _table;
        }
        set
        {
            _table = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Table);
        }
    }

    private string _startDate;
    public string startDate
    {
        get { return _startDate;  }
        set
        {
            _startDate = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(startDate);
        }
    }

    private string _endDate;
    public string endDate
    {
        get { return _endDate; }
        set
        {
            _startDate = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(endDate);
        }
    }

    private string _productName;
    public string productName
    {
        get { return _productName; }
        set
        {
            _startDate = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(productName);
        }
    }

    private string _category;
    public string category
    {
        get { return _category; }
        set
        {
            _startDate = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(category);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor for the view model
    /// </summary>
    public ShellViewModel()
    {
        //Table = new DataTable();
        Init();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets up Analytics service and makes a request
    /// </summary>
    private void Init()
    {
        // start mananger
        // required component for authentication
        // todo: a more secure way of storing and reading the client secrets
        var clientSecret = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\client_secrets.json";
        _manager = new AnalyticsManager(clientSecret);

        // set the static ID for the project we're pulling data from
        _manager.LoadAnalyticsProfiles();
        _manager.SetDefaultAnalyticProfile("12345678");

        // todo: define metrics, dimensions, and filters using the UI
        // define "x value" metrics

        var metrics = new List<DataItem>();
        metrics.Add(EventTracking.Metrics.uniqueEvents);
        //metrics.Add(Session.Metrics.visits);

        // define "y value" dimensions
        var dimensions = new List<DataItem>();
        dimensions.Add(EventTracking.Dimensions.eventCategory);
        dimensions.Add(GeoNetwork.Dimensions.country);
        //dimensions.Add(GeoNetwork.Dimensions.city);

        // filter by something to reduce the size of the request
        var filters = new List<DataItem>();

        var country = new DataItem(GeoNetwork.Dimensions.country.Name);
        country.Equals("United States");
        filters.Add(country);

        var eventCategory = new DataItem(EventTracking.Dimensions.eventCategory.Name);
        //eventCategory.Contains("277");
        //filters.Add(eventCategory);

        // get table from Google and set to view property
        Table = _manager.GetGaDataTable(DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30), DateTime.Today, metrics, dimensions, filters, metrics, true);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What you should do is use two-way bindings on the 4 inputs (startDate, etc).  That way the values will already be there in the view-model when you invoke the command.

Comment: ^ Or use `CommandParameter`.

Comment: @Mike: actually I believe the preferred method is to use the data bindings. I have no idea why but I've read it in several places now. It surprised me because I preferred command parameters myself for years...I guess the one thing it does help ensure is that you never wind up working with an object outside the set of objects you think you're bound to?

Comment: @MarkFeldman For my own preference, I like to ensure that commands that need parameters use the `CommandParameter`, where each command in my class has it's own method with an argument. For example: `myMethod(myType parameter)` instead of just `myMethod()`. The reason for this is it seems to make things easier when writing unit tests as the developer doesn't have to worry about setting any properties before calling a method that's attached to a command, they simply call the method and provide the parameter. It's kinda hard to explain but I hope that made some sense.